# Aligning buttons and input form in mobile screen size - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a text input and 3 buttons:

```
<div class = "container"
    <input type="text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Input here">
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

I know that normally I could use `form-inline` but that does not work for smaller screen sizes. With a mobile screen size, how do I align the buttons and input form so that it is on one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't use bootstrap, but you can add

```
display: flex
```

to the container div.

https://jsfiddle.net/cb95vs5p/

Comment: Works perfectly. What does `display:flex` do exactly?

Comment: @ecain Basically it is an entire layout mode that is made to be flexible (responsive). It can do a bunch of things besides this. If you are interested [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is an overview.

Answer (score 0):

Put all three `button`s and the `input` in a `div` with the class of `row`, and then give each element its own `div` with the class of `col-xs-3`.
This will arrange them on a line and assign each element 1/4 of the available width.